# 一趟 vs 一次、is there any difference?

Tags: difference

Under the entry 趟 my dictionary says:

> 1. For round trip
> 2. For single train trip

Does this mean, when I see this word I must assume the speaker  went back and forth, except when he went by train, where I must assume a single trip?

This startles me very much, since knowledge of the means of transportation would be required, in order to correctly interpret the sentence!

Does 趟 imply that the speaker is now away from the place in question? So, does:

> 我去過北京兩趟。

mean I am not in Beijing? Is this a difference between 趟 and 次？

Comment: 次 more general than 趟，both function as verbal measure words,in fact "外国人实用汉语语发＂has the following list of 动量词 with matching verbs/可以和量搭词配的动词： **次**  ：去找来参观｜遍：看说写念听抄翻译｜下儿：打敲摇想玩讨论｜ **趟**   ：去来｜回：看送｜场：下（雨）打（球）｜阵：刮（风）｜顿：吃打骂，动量词大多用在动词后边作补语，表示数量。例如： **我们讨论两次。我去一趟。**  enter 次、趟 into jukuu for more examples,also find 100 samples for "round trip",e.g. 您买单程票还是买往返票?

Comment: as jukuu's sample sentences will show 趟 is used as verbal measure word for any number of trips by any means of transportation, bus,train (subway),plane,or walking, climbing, wading through water, swimming, for trips to the super market or the police station, "round trip" may be implied, but cannot find any dictionary that supplies it as translation.

Answer (score 4):

*My English is not good. This answer translated by Google Translate.*

Nowadays these two words are mixed and there is no serious mistake. But here are some explanations.

### 趟

`趟` is generally used for round trips in a specified time. Example:

> 我今天去了兩趟超市。
>
> *I went to the supermarket twice today*

I went and came back twice. Now I'm home.

### 次

`次` emphasizes **number of travels** and your experience from the trip. Example:

> 我去過两次北京。
>
> *I went to Beijing twice.*

I just want to tell you that I have that trip.

Answer (score 1):

> Does this mean, when I see this word I must assume the speaker went back and forth, except when he went by train, where I must assume a single trip?

Neither one is indicating a "went back and forth" situation. You can't tell that from just this one sentence.

> Does 趟 imply that the speaker is now away from the place in question? So, does:

No.

The usage of 一趟 and 一次 are quite similar, 趟 is more often used for trips or travels. 次 serve a more general purpose.

Answer (score 0):

these two words are verb modifiers. they mean the same thing when you're modifying verbs with related to travel/move/go. 趟 can be used with moving verbs or verbs that are related to moving, going, traveling only, while 次 is an universal verb modifier that can be used with any verb.

here are four examples:

我和你妈出三趟街。 (good) I go out with your mom three times. 出 is the verb.

我和你妈出三次街。 (good) I go out with your mom three times. 出 is the verb.

我和你妈吃三趟饭。 (good) I go out with your mom three times to eat. 吃 is the verb here, but 趟 modified the verb 吃 into 出去吃。

我和你妈吃三次饭。 (good) I eat mom three times. 吃 is also the verb here, but 次 here only modified the number of time 吃。吃了 three times. Note, this sentence doesn't imply going out to eat.

Comment: amazing and very amusing examples, so I don't understand why do people downvote this answer :D